# Prevent user to perform any actions while page is loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a tabbed web application, and I also created caching of the images before page transitions, so when the user goes to a page, I make sure all the images are downloaded before transitioning to that page.

When I click on a tab with many images, I display a spinner and starts downloading the images in the background then after it finishes I will display the page.

But I want to freeze any user inputs or taps while I'm doing this. So what is the best method to freeze and unfreeze the whole page?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a predefined jQuery UI called [**jQuery Block UI**](http://jquery.malsup.com)

Or simply add a division that will block  the body and will fade out when the body is loaded.

```
<div id="div">
    <h1>Please Wait..</h1>
</div>
```

jQuery will be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div").fadeOut()
  });
```

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/UHuKG/1/) is the working Example. The page will be blocked until the image is loaded completely.

Answer (score 2):

This JQuery code can disable elements on page:

```
$("body").find("*").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("body").find("a").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

And this JQuery code will make elements enabled again:

```
$("body").find("*").removeAttr("disabled");
$("body").find("a").unbind("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

Covering the interface with a top-level transparent/translucent overlay should block events for elements beneath it.

However, you would be taking UI control away from the user by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
$(window).bind('load', function() {
    // code here
});
```

Until the page is not completely loaded this event is not fired. So, there, you can call a function that unlock your page's elements.

Enjoy :)