# pre-load a webpage before viewing

Tags: html, image-preloader

I have a Wordpress site that has numerous large images (full screen background image scroller) and when I go to my page it goes 'pixel-ly' and looks broken until fully loaded.

What is the proper procedure to load a websites images so the users first look at the site isn't broken or glitched?

Answer (score 0):

Hide everything until the page is loaded. Show a loading screen in the meantime if you want.

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'block';">

<div id="loading">Some loading text or icon goes here...</div>

<div id="content" style="display:none;">Main content goes here...</div>
```

Comment: content can be any name?

Comment: @user3550879 Correct, you can change the id "content" to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Block page from user interaction until all images/components are loaded. It isn't too complex - use jQuery.
it is already answered in

[prevent user to perform any actions while page is loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052819/prevent-user-to-perform-any-actions-while-page-is-loading)

Comment: the jquery in the example doesnt work (at least in firefox)

Comment: so basically, there are plugins available in jQuery to achieve it. You may choose one that works for your browser. Search for block UI jquery plugins.